# JAVA american to canadian translation

Tags: java

I'm making a simple program to enter American spelling and to output Canadian spelling. For example, honor -> honour, or color -> colour. Works, but not all the time. I have no clue why.

Solved; it wasn't working because single characters did not enjoy this code ->`secondLastLetter = word.charAt(wordLength - 2);`

Here's the finished code, works with full sentences, the words to be translated cannot have suffixes.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class XXXXCanadian
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {  
    BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String lowerInput = ""; // declaring variable to work outside the loop

    while (!lowerInput.equals("quit"))
    {
      System.out.print ("Please enter a sentence to translate (Enter 'quit' to leave)");
      String input = objReader.readLine ();

      lowerInput = input.toLowerCase(); // any form of "quit" will make the loop exit

      Translate newSentence = new Translate(input);
      String output = newSentence.getOutput();

      System.out.println (output); // printing output
    }
  }
}


class Translate
{
  // declaring variables
  private String word = "";
  private String newWord = "";
  private String line = "";
  private String output = "";
  private char lastLetter;
  private char secondLastLetter;
  private int wordLength;

  Translate(String l)
  {
    line = l;
    Translation();
    getOutput(); // accessor method
  }


  private void Translation()
  {
    Scanner freader = new Scanner(line);
    StringBuffer newPhrase = new StringBuffer ("");

    while (freader.hasNext())
    {
      String word = freader.next();
      wordLength = word.length(); // gets the length of each word

      if (wordLength >= 5)
      {
        lastLetter = word.charAt(wordLength - 1);
        secondLastLetter = word.charAt(wordLength - 2);

        if (secondLastLetter == 'o' && lastLetter == 'r') // last two letters must be "OR"
        {
          String word2 = word.substring(0, wordLength - 2); // extracts all letters but the "OR"
          newWord = word2.concat("our"); // adds "OUR" to the end of the word
        }
        else
        {
          newWord = word; // keeps the same word
        }
      }
      else
      {
        newWord = word;
      }

      newPhrase.append(newWord);
      newPhrase.append(' '); // add a space
      output = newPhrase.toString(); // convert back to a string
    }
  }

  String getOutput()
  {
    return output; // returns the whole output
  }
}
```

Comment: What are some examples where it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is not working and add it to your question?

Comment: Do you wish to append a U to every single O?  (Or only doing this for a specific group).

Comment: @ne1410s it looks like he's changing 'or' to 'our' at the ends of words. At least, that's what the code looks like.

Comment: Do you understand that a bunch of the examples aren't correct? Or at least, they wouldn't be for British English. (We have scissors, pastors, castor oil, etc.)

Comment: I only need U's added to a word that has more than 4 letters. The first two examples work, the second two don't. I know that it wouldn't work for a bunch of words, but it's how the assignment is supposed to be.

Comment: As @JonSkeet implied, I'd suggest just checking your inputs against a list of words that actually fit the rule. Also, I'd be worried about your implementation and words like 'colored', 'colors', 'coloring', etc.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Yes I'm aware it wouldn't work for those words, but I don't need it to. I'm just wondering why it doesn't work. I'll try that though.

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM. When entering a single character or number, it gives me an error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check the length of the word and decide to parse it *before* you use .charAt().  If there's only one character, what is the value of .charAt(1-2)?

Comment: There is no such thing as CANADIAN spelling.  There is English(US) and English(UK). What you are calling "Canadian" spelling is actually UK spelling.

Comment: I KNOW THERE IS NO SUCH THING AS CANADIAN SPELLING. This is a school assignment. I'm a beginner in java. My teacher isn't very creative. This is what he came up with.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you have a single character string ("a" for example) and you do this?

```
String str = "a";
int wordLength = str.length();
str.charAt(wordLength - 2);
```

Since wordLength = 1, wordLength-2 = -1 which isn't a valid index into a String.

The same problem would come up if you did this:

```
String str = "";
int wordLength = str.length();
str.charAt(wordLength - 2);
```

OR

```
str.charAt(wordLength - 1);
```

Since wordLength = 0

What you need to do is check your wordLength before you continue:

```
int wordLength = input.length();
if(wordLength >= 5)
{
    // find last letters
    // do your check/replacement
}
```

Comment: If you use a suitable regular expression then a lot of this is pointless

Comment: That's true but I don't think his teacher wants that solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I noticed when entering single characters that it would give me an error.

Comment: I hope this helps you with your program.  You would have an error for empty string (no characters), and single character strings - do you understand *why* though?  It seems that the purpose of this exercise is to give you exposure to the concept of strings and indices.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I had the `char secondLastLetter = word.charAt(wordLength - 2)` dealing with all the words. I had to make a separate if statement for the short words and then put the `char secondLastLetter` within the if statement that takes care of words that I have to "translate".

Comment: Yes it's a **very** unrealistic assignment, but the teacher makes new projects every year to prevent people just copying previous years. So 10+ projects a year, I would think some of them are not the most practical. We've also only been programming for 4 months.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you figure it out and best of luck in school.

Comment: Also: it's customary to mark an answer as Accepted when it helped you with the problem, as to direct others to the solution easily.  It's also nice because it gives out fancy internet points.